# Display collation in create table output

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm writing a set of SQL statements in MySQL to create and modify a few tables. I need to get my output to match a document of sample output exactly (this is for school).

When I show my create table statements, all varchar columns need to look like this:

```
`name` varchar(10) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
```

but they weren't showing the collation. I tried changing the declaration to

```
name varchar COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
```

but this caused the output to show both the charset and collation, and I need to be showing just the collation.  The sample output document was created on Unix, while I am on Windows, so this could be the source of the difference, but I need to know for sure.

Is there a way I can alter my queries to show collation or is this just a Unix Windows inconsistency?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be honest, I doubt very much that anyone intends for you to obtain output that is identical *verbatem*—it's more likely that they require it to be identical *semantically*.  However, you might play around with the table's default charset/collation to see whether that makes a difference to the output obtained from `SHOW CREATE TABLE`:

```
ALTER TABLE foo CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE ut8_bin;
```

Failing that, it could be a difference between MySQL versions.

Comment: The grader is automated, so yes, as stupid as it sounds, it has to be verbatim.